# issue with passwords with special character (#) using read_default_file

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

I'm relatively new to Django and am looking to read my MySQL connection info from a file using the read_default_file process. I test this on Windows and it seems to work perfectly. I move to my linux pre-prod server and i get an issue access issue. Through countless hours of testing, i find that the issue seems to be with my password contains a special character # and it seems that this process is translating that to mean the start of a comment. I have no control over the password and need to be able to handle this character. on a side note, if i load the details directly into my django app (settings.py) then i have no issue and all is fine, but if i try to offload them into my conenction file, this situation arises.

I have looked but cannot seem to find a way to escape the PW to handle this character (and arguably others). What am i missing and is there a way to handle passwords with special characters like my situation?

Cheers!

Comment: This [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74482) suggests wrapping the password with double quotes -> `"my#password"`

Comment: Note that this is really about MySQL options files, it's got nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't even thinking of it from a MySQL perspective. TYVM for the redirection and it works perfectly. cheers!